# How do you enter a Koopa Shell?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world

The title screen for Super Mario 3D World shows Peach picking up and [entering a Koopa Shell](https://youtu.be/VZYiXgKmHks?t=1m20s). I don’t remember this mechanic being explained, despite finishing the game 100%.

How do you enter a Koopa Shell in Super Mario 3D World?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enter a shell, press the crouch button while holding a Koopa Shell. To exit a shell, release the run/hold button.

While in a shell, you can steer left and right as you spin forward. You can also jump while in a shell. If you stay in the shell for too long, your character will become dizzy.